java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null in WebSphere when Payload Size Increases
I'm encountering an issue in my Spring Boot application hosted on WebSphere. When the payload size increases, the application throws the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString(RequestUtils.java:288)
    ...

This error occurs when processing a POST request with a large payload. However, the same functionality works perfectly fine with smaller payloads.
Here’s my @InitBinder configuration:
@InitBinder
public void dataBinding(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(4500);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}

I've set the collection limit to 4500, which worked for smaller payloads. But as the payload size grows, the application fails with the below exception. The stack trace indicates the failure occurs in:
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString(RequestUtils.java:288)

Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString(RequestUtils.java:288)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString(RequestUtils.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.RequestUtils.parsePostData(RequestUtils.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.RequestUtils.parsePostDataLong(RequestUtils.java:396)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters(SRTServletRequest.java:2398)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getParameterMap(SRTServletRequest.java:3042)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameterMap(ServletRequestWrapper.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest.getParameterMap(StrictHttpFirewall.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameterMap(ServletRequestWrapper.java:203)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameterMap(ServletRequestWrapper.java:203)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameterMap(ServletRequestWrapper.java:203)
    at com.vayana.boot.infra.web.security.filter.XSSRequestWrapper.<init>(XSSRequestWrapper.java:34)
    at com.vayana.boot.infra.web.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:966)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

Steps I've Tried:
Increased the binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit.

Validated the payload size by testing with smaller data.

Observations:
It works for payloads of smaller sizes (e.g., 600 entries).

The error is triggered when the payload exceeds a certain size.

Questions:
1. Is there a specific WebSphere configuration or limit that needs adjustment to handle larger payloads?
2. Could this be related to request parameter or query string size limits in WebSphere? If so, how can I modify the relevant configurations?
3. Are there any other settings or methods to handle large payloads effectively in WebSphere or Spring Boot?
4. Could the issue also be related to a Web Application Firewall (WAF) in place in our production environment that imposes a strict limit on the request body length? If so, how can we configure Spring Boot to handle larger payloads effectively without triggering WAF restrictions?
Environment:
WebSphere Application Server 9
Spring Boot 2.7.18.
Java 8

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT:
In our production environment, we have a Web Application Firewall (WAF) in place to enhance security. However, this WAF imposes a strict limit on the request body length, which has become a challenge for handling large payloads. As a result, we are encountering issues where requests that exceed this limit are being rejected, causing disruptions in the functionality of our application. Is there a simple way to handle it using Spring Boot.

Which spring boot version? Plesae add the full stacktrace. At first glance this appears to be a WebSphere issue and not so much a Spring (Boot) issue as the only classes listed in the stacktrace so far are from WebSphere.

Full Stack Trace I have added in question

Judging from the stacktrace it is a websphere issue, as the error comes from websphere when trying to read the request. Or your request is just to large, there is a maximum length for the URL and request parameters if you exceed that you are probably in trouble.

I noticed that the stack trace error also points to org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest.getParameterMap in Spring Boot. Has anyone encountered a similar issue related to Spring Security’s HTTP firewall configuration? Could this be caused by a specific WebSphere configuration, or is it more likely a Spring Boot configuration issue?"

As stated the error originates from WebSphere not from Spring. Hence a WebSphere issue. Either configuration or you are running into a limitation (which is quite likely with large requests). I try to stay far away from things like WebSphere the last couple of years, so what to configure and on what level (cluster, node, app or whatever) I have no idea.

Based on the info provided, it looks like you're hitting the following error:
Exceeding.maximum.parameters=SRVE0325E: Exceeding maximum parameters allowed per request {0} ,current {1} , cannot add more.
Exceeding.maximum.parameters.explanation=The number of parameters contained in the inbound request exceeds the maximum number of parameters that can be included in a inbound request.
Exceeding.maximum.parameters.useraction=Ensure that all of the parameters in the inbound request are valid, and that the total number parameters does not exceed the maximum allowed per request.

Please check the logs to see if you see this message.
The max number of request params can be configured via com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxparamperrequest.  By default, it is set to 10000.
Trying changing the config to see if you can get the exception to go away.

This specific error message is not present in the logs. Additionally, we have a Web Application Firewall (WAF) implemented in production, which enforces a limit on the request body length. This suggests that the issue might not be related to the maxparamperrequest setting but rather to the WAF-imposed request size restriction.
